# Single source of truth for Python project version in presence of pyproject.toml

Tags: python, version, pyproject.toml

The pyproject.toml specification affords the ability to specify the project version, e.g.

```
[project]
name = "foo"
version = "0.0.1"
```

However, it is also a common Python idiom to put `__version__ = "0.0.1"` in `foo/__init__.py` so that users can query it.

Is there a standard way of extracting the `version` from the `pyproject.toml` and getting it into the `foo/__init__.py`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take here.

1. Keep version in `pyproject.toml` and get it from the package metadata in the source code. So, in your `mypkg/__init__.py` or wherever:

   ```
   from importlib.metadata import version
   __version__ = version("mypkg")
   ```

   [`importlib.metadata.version`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions) is available since Python 3.8.  For earlier Python versions, you can do similar with the [`importlib_metadata`](https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#importlib_metadata.version) backport.
2. Keep the version in the source code and instruct the build system to get it from there. For a setuptools build backend, it looks like this in `pyproject.toml`:

   ```
   [project]
   name = "mypkg"
   dynamic = ["version"]

   [tool.setuptools.dynamic]
   version = {attr = "mypkg.__version__"}
   ```

My recommendation is () ... *neither*! Don't keep a `__version__` attribute in the source code at all. It's an outdated habit which we can do without these days. `Version` is already a *required* field in the [package metadata](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/#core-metadata-specifications), it's redundant to keep the same string as an attribute in the package/module namespace.

Comment: What if a user wants to do something in their code which depends on the version in my code? How can they recover my code's version with a `foo.__version__`?

Comment: Users would do it the same way as demonstrated in point 1: by calling `version("yourpackage")`. As you said in the question, this attribute is just a "common Python idiom" so it's not like `module.__version__` is reliable in general anyway (it might or might not be there). Getting the metadata version _is_ reliable because it's guaranteed to be there for an installed package (ref [_PEP 566 – Metadata for Python Software Packages 2.1_](https://peps.python.org/pep-0566/)).

Comment: If you've already provided a `__version__` attribute in previous releases, and need to preserve backwards compatibility, take your pick of 1. or 2., but for new projects I think it's best not to put the `__version__` attribute in the first place.

Comment: @wim Could you please elaborate a bit more on how the version is determined for the purpose of creating package metadata? I went through the [packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and from that, I thought that when a wheel is created by `python3 -m build`, version metadata is set according to the value in `pyproject.toml`. 
However, judging from your answer, I must have missed something important. If the version is not in `pyproject.toml`, how does the `build` script determine it?

Comment: @Matej Have a read PEP517, in particular the [`prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/#prepare-metadata-for-build-wheel) hook specifications. `build` will invoke the PEP517 hooks, and the build backend (setuptools in this example) will collect the version number from somewhere (from the attribute `foo.__version__` in this example, but in general may be from somewhere else such as from the VCS). How setuptools itself will access a `__version__` attribute has changed over time, I think current releases attempt to do it using an ast parse (to avoid actually importing)